# Track traffic sourcse in Google Analytics Nuxt module

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-analytics, nuxt.js

I ve recently implemented Google Analytics module for my Nuxt website.

I did it by installing the module then configuring it in nuxt.config.js as follows:

```
gtm: {
        id: 'GTM-WGW****'
    },
    googleAnalytics: {
        id: 'UA-230******-*'
    },
```

Event tracking is working very good when it comes to purchases but for some reason when I want to see the source of the event (ex: google, facebook etc) all it shows is Stripe. So i get no source data about the user that is browsing my website.

I have tried using rudderstack in combination with this Nuxt module but it doubles my traffic (as it should)

Do you have any solution for how I can track traffic source using the Nuxt Google Analytics module ? (`'@nuxtjs/google-analytics'`)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after joining the Stripe discord and some more reading, the only way is to go
in your GA dashboard and add `stripe.com` and `checkout.stripe.com` to the refer exclussion list.

Happy coding!